# Mysql Return ID where last activity is older than X Days

Tags: php, mysql, performance

i have a log tabel where every user activity is stored.

UserActivityTable (arround 15Milion records)

```
  id    userID    category           value                 timestamp 
    1        2         Visit          homepage          2018-02-21 13:13:54
    1        2         Visit          page2             2018-02-18 13:13:45
    1        2         Visit          page1             2018-02-15 13:13:30
    1        3         Visit          homepage          2018-02-01 13:13:12
```

With an SQL query i need to get all userID´s where the last activity is older than X Days (lets say 30) if the user is set to "Active"

Users(arround 15k User)

```
id     Groups     Active   Name    Mails ...
2      Customer    1       Hans
3      Customer    0       Wurst
```

if i get all user that active (arround 5k) and than try to get there last activity i run into a timeout (the query is not perfomant i think)
If i limit it to 5 there is no problem.

What i try.

1 Select of all User that are active, than use a foreach function to get there last activity if its older than 30 days i write it inside new array and at the end i use that array to set the activity inside the user table to false.

Untill the last 2-3 Month it was just fine but now we have a lot of new users and the function cant handle it.

Is there a clean way to get all that stuff in one sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the `Users`:

```
SELECT `userID`, MAX(`timestamp`) AS lastActive FROM `UserActivityTable` 
WHERE `userID` IN (
    SELECT `id` FROM `Users` WHERE `Active` = 1
) GROUP BY `userID` HAVING lastActive < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

**Indexing**

- You should use a [`PRIMARY KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) index on the `Users` table.
- You should use a [`FOREIGN KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) index on `UserActivityTable` table.
- To speed up the query above you can create a column index on `timestamp` column.

You can use the following to create a [`INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on the `timestamp` column:

```
CREATE INDEX index_timestamp ON `UserActivityTable` (`timestamp`);
```

---

You can also use a single query to `UPDATE` the `active` state on the `Users` table:

```
UPDATE `Users` SET `active` = EXISTS (
    SELECT `userID` FROM `UserActivityTable` WHERE `UserActivityTable`.`userID` = `Users`.`id` GROUP BY `UserActivityTable`.`userID` HAVING MAX(`UserActivityTable`.`timestamp`) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
)
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the necessary [mysql indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: `DATE_SUB` with an underscore

Comment: DATESUB is SQL-server

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a clean way to get all that stuff in one sql query?

**Yes**, you can **update** the `Users` table in a single step with the following query:

```
UPDATE `Users` SET `Active` = EXISTS(
    SELECT * from `UserActivityTable ` WHERE
        `UserActivityTable `.`userID` = `Users`.`id` AND
        `timestamp`>DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY )
    )
```

The `EXISTS` statement returns `1` or `0` depending if does esists at least one record in the user activity in the last 30 days. So the field `Active` is properly updated to `1` or `0` for every user.

---

> Mysql Return ID where last activity is older than X Days

If you just want the list of users' id with activity you have:

```
SELECT `Users`.`id` WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * from `UserActivityTable ` WHERE
        `UserActivityTable `.`userID` = `Users`.`id` AND
        `timestamp`>DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY )
    ) = 1
```

---

In order to have good performaces (at least) the field `timestamp` must be indexed.

---

**Side note**

You already hit 15M records.

As your events table will grow indefinitely over time you should consider deleting periodically old entries or moving them to a separate table/dump file.

Comment: Hey Paolo, thanks for your side note. We delete the activity tabe for inaktive user after 30 days (so they are stored for 60 days in total if someone is inaktive) most of the stuff is from aktive user and are needed in some ways. We also archive after 1 Year but yea you are right maybe i should change that to every half year

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.

It is improper to have redundant information in a database.  (`active` is redundant because it can be discovered by a query against `UserActivityTable`.)

OK, you need more performance, so you are setting this flag.  I assume this is not a one-time task, but needs to be updated daily?  Or what?  I ask this because `active=0` will be wrong if the 'user' does something *after* you run the `UPDATE`, and before running it again!

Let's solve that *bug*, then discover that we are making the `UPDATE` very fast in the process.

The 'only' way to fix that bug is to reach into `UserActivityTable` dynamically.  However, we can make that so cheap that it is OK to do it in 'realtime'.

```
FROM Users
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM UserActivityTable
                 WHERE userID = x.userID
                   AND timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY )  -- == "active"

UserActivityTable needs INDEX(userID, timestamp)
```

Oops!  I just obviated the need for the `active` column.

One of your Comments mentioned purging 'old, inactive' users??  Is the `UPDATE` aimed at that?  Please fold *that* requirement into the question, else I (and others) are not necessarily helping you.